# Matlab - Plot areas of interest onto an image

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm working on an application and I'm at a stage where I'm comparing two images to see if they have any resemblance, with one another. I have managed to do this, an example you can find [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKxFj.png).

From the image, it will display white spaces for pixels that are near the same for both images given. What I want to do next is get the coordinates of the white spaces and plot them onto the [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VFkb.png) to highlight the strongest features about the coin. However, I'm unsure how to do this as I'm rather new to Matlab.

```
firstImage = sprintf('M:/Project/MatLab/Coin Image Processing/Image Processing/test-1.jpg');
secondImage = sprintf('M:/Project/MatLab/Coin Image Processing/Image Processing/test-99.jpg');

a = rgb2gray(imread(firstImage));
b = rgb2gray(imread(secondImage));

axes(handles.axes4);
imshow(a==b);
title('Scanning For Strongest Features', 'fontweight', 'bold')
```

From using `disp(a==b)`,  I can see which points of both pictures are the same. So my guess is that I need to do something where I get the coordinates of all the zeroes and then plot them onto the original image in a way that highlights it, similar to using a yellow highlighter, but I just don't know how.

Comment: `text=sprintf('a')` is just a verbose way of doing `text='a'`

Comment: Oh yeah, just copied the line from a previous section where I needed to use user input, just forgot to change it

Comment: No worries then, just letting you know. Consider looking to previous questions and accepting them if they helped you.

Comment: Could you post both the images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got your question, I think you should use `find` to collect all the coordinates for which `a==b`:

```
[X, Y] = find(a == b); % Find coordinates for which the two images are equal
imshow(a), axis image; % Show first image
hold on
plot(Y, X, 'y.'); % Overlay those coordinates
hold off
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a transparent overlay to plot the region of interest.

```
figure
imshow(originalImage); % plot the original image
hold on
% generate a red overlay
overlay(:, :, 1) = ones(size(a)); % red channel
overlay(:, :, 2) = zeros(size(a)); % green channel
overlay(:, :, 3) = zeros(size(a)); % blue channel
h = imshow(overlay); %  plot the overlay
set(h, 'AlphaData', (a == b) * 0.5); % set the transparency to 50% if a == b and 0% otherwise
```